# How to access internet from azure point to site vpn (Not working)?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, openvpn, azure-vpn

I set up the Point to site vpn in azure vnet with virtual network gateway which is working fine using openvpn . Now i can able to connect to azure vm via private ip but i could not able to access internet from my Host Machine (Local machine where i connected my vpn ).

**Before VPN Set up i can able to connect to  Internet Please click below for ping results  **

[Before VPN connected ping results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU3EG.png)

**After VPN Set up i cannot able to connect to Internet Please click below for ping results **

[After VPN connected ping results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYlsz.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the Host Machine to be blocked something must have changed on the Host machine or on the subnet on which it is located.

When setting up a VPN, you should set up a gateway subnet that is used only for that.

Have you used the subnet on which the VM is located as the gateway subnet?

Comment: I have only **1 Vnet(10.0.2.0/24)** , In this Vnet i had **4 subnets**  ( `default(10.0.2.0/24)`,`containers(10.0.4.0/24)`,`nat-subnet(10.0.6.0/24)`,`GatewaySubnet(10.0.5.0/27)` )

All of my vm are default subnet